# RAW RSA encryption and decryption with Crypto++

Tags: rsa, crypto++

I need to establish a secure communication between a PC and a device which supports RSA encryption and signature with SHA1. As I have already used Crypto++ in other parts of my application, I would like to utilize Crypto++ for this as well.

The device is very primitive but allows executing a program I write on it. It has raw RSA and SHAa functions built-in; However, it has very little memory to work with, 2K bytes to be precise.

I have to encrypt and sign a message from a PC. Then the device decrypts and verifies the message. The device will then reply an encrypted message and sign on it. The PC will decrypt the message and verify it afterwards. I have implemented the raw RSA encryption, signature and verification with SHA1 inside the device using the built-in functions. The messages is short enough to be done in a single round.

However, I don't know how to encrypt a message with raw RSA using Crypto++ without involving OAEP or PKCS#1. Could somebody kind enough to show me some sample code? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know how to encrypt a message with raw RSA using Crypto++ without
> involving OAEP or PKCS#1. Could somebody kind enough to show me some sample code?

That's easy enough when you know where to look: [Raw RSA](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA) from the Crypto++ wiki. The code below was taken from the page.

---

**Encryption**

```cpp
Integer n("0xbeaadb3d839f3b5f"), e("0x11"), d("0x21a5ae37b9959db9");

RSA::PublicKey pubKey;
pubKey.Initialize(n, e);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Integer m, c;
string message = "secret";  

cout << "message: " << message << endl;

// Treat the message as a big endian byte array
m = Integer((const byte *)message.data(), message.size());
cout << "m: " << hex << m << endl;

// Encrypt
c = pubKey.ApplyFunction(m);
cout << "c: " << hex << c << endl;
```

---

**Decryption**

```cpp
Integer n("0xbeaadb3d839f3b5f"), e("0x11"), d("0x21a5ae37b9959db9");
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

RSA::PrivateKey privKey;
privKey.Initialize(n, e, d);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Integer c("0x3f47c32e8e17e291"), r;
string recovered;

// Decrypt
r = privKey.CalculateInverse(prng, c);
cout << "r: " << hex << r << endl;

// Round trip the message
size_t req = r.MinEncodedSize();
recovered.resize(req);
r.Encode((byte *)recovered.data(), recovered.size());

cout << "recovered: " << recovered << endl;
```

---

Here's a sample output:

```
$ ./cryptopp-raw-rsa.exe
message: secret
m: 736563726574h
c: 3f47c32e8e17e291h
r: 736563726574h
recovered: secret
```

---

There is one caveat: `c = m ^ e mod n`, so there are some limits on plaint text size and cipher text size. Essentially, `m` and `c` must be smaller than `n`. In this example, replacing the string `secret` with `now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country` would fail because it's larger than `n` when converted to an `Integer`.

You can get the maximum plain text size with the function `MaxPreImage()`, and the maximum cipher text size with `MaxImage()`.

---

> I have to encrypt and sign a message from a PC. Then the device decrypts
> and verifies the message. The device will then reply an encrypted message
> and sign on it. The PC will decrypt the message and verify it afterwards.

On the surface, this looks like it will suffer replay attacks. You might need a protocol with the protection.

Comment: `m = Integer((const byte *)message.data(), message.size());` could anybody be able to explain how is big-endian byte* converted to Integer?

Comment: @Laxman - The `byte*, size` pair is wrapped in a `Store`, which gives it a `BufferedTransformation` front-end. Then `Integer::Decode` is called. Also see [`integer.cpp : 3356`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/integer.cpp#L3356).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demo function I wrote when I first did RSA encryption and decryption with Crypto++. I wrote it just to understand the basics. I hope it helps:

```cpp
#include <cryptopp/files.h>
#include <cryptopp/modes.h>
#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
#include <cryptopp/rsa.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>

using namespace CryptoPP;

void rsa_examples()
{
    // Keys created here may be used by OpenSSL.
    //
    // openssl pkcs8 -in key.der -inform DER -out key.pem -nocrypt 
    // openssl rsa -in key.pem -check

    AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

    // Create a private RSA key and write it to a file using DER.
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor priv( rng, 4096 );
    TransparentFilter privFile( new FileSink("rsakey.der") );
    priv.DEREncode( privFile );
    privFile.MessageEnd();

    // Create a private RSA key and write it to a string using DER (also write to a file to check it with OpenSSL).
    std::string the_key;
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor pri( rng, 2048 );
    TransparentFilter privSink( new StringSink(the_key) );
    pri.DEREncode( privSink );
    privSink.MessageEnd();

    std::ofstream file ( "key.der", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary );
    file.write( the_key.data(), the_key.size() );
    file.close();

    // Example Encryption & Decryption
    InvertibleRSAFunction params;
    params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize( rng, 1536 );

    std::string plain = "RSA Encryption", cipher, decrypted_data;

    RSA::PrivateKey privateKey( params );
    RSA::PublicKey publicKey( params );

    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e( publicKey );
    StringSource( plain, true, new PK_EncryptorFilter( rng, e, new StringSink( cipher )));

    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor d( privateKey );
    StringSource( cipher, true, new PK_DecryptorFilter( rng, d, new StringSink( decrypted_keydata )));

    assert( plain == decrypted_data );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I understand your code. However, my situation is a little bit different.

Comment: That code does RSA encryption and decryption. If that's not what you want, I'll just delete it.

Comment: Sorry that the comment was posted with return key but I was just intended to insert a line.

I have further elaborated my situation in the subject for clearance.

I really appreciate your help. ^_^

Comment: Purpose and function of PK_EncryptorFilter is unclear